# Socket.io doesn't work properly

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I made a realtime chart showing system load every second. It works fine in my local mechine but after I deploy it to the server, there is a long delay before the data is sent back from the server. Also, I excepted the data is sent back every second but it sends data in a irregular interval.

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function (socket) {
    var sysinfo = setInterval(function(){
        socket.emit('system_info',{
            time:Date.now(),
            load:os.loadavg(),
            memory:os.totalmem()-os.freemem()
        });
    },3000);

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        clearInterval(sysinfo);
    });
});
```

[Here is the chart](http://licson-node.hp.af.cm/system/chart)

[Here is the source code](http://licson-node.hp.af.cm/index.js)

Comment: what is the actual question?

Comment: It has a long delay before data arrives and the data is sent back in a irregular interval.

Comment: If you inspect the network traffic, is it still  connecting with a Websocket when deployed? Maybe it is falling back to another transport for the server but using Websockets on your local system.

Comment: @loganfsmyth After a check I did find that it's falling back to xhr polling but I still don't get it. Is it the server's problem or mine?

Comment: @user1823713 That would probably explain the slowness then. What hosting service are you using? Do they support websockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've describe it as "*every second*," but your interval is set to `3000` or "*every **3** seconds*."

For the "*irregular interval*," intervals are not guaranteed to be exact.

From [Globals](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_setinterval_cb_ms):

> Note that the actual interval may vary, depending on external factors like OS timer granularity and system load. It's never less than `ms` but it may be longer.

From [Timers](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg):

> It is important to note that your callback will probably not be called in exactly `delay` milliseconds - Node.js makes no guarantees about the exact timing of when the callback will fire, nor of the ordering things will fire in. The callback will be called as close as possible to the time specified.

Comment: Well sorry that I described wrongly but I need to wait for minutes to see the data come back sometimes.